# GET information in Flask over HTTP

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to save some information in my localStorage by fetching it over HTTP. But, I am not getting any output.

Here is the code:

```
{% if ( current_user.is_authenticated()) %}
<li class="list-group-item {% if active_link=="settings"%}active{% endif %}"><a href="{{url_for('project.settings', short_name=project.short_name)}}">{{_('Settings')}}</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i></li>
{% endif %}
```

Here, we are getting the current_user information using Flask that is fetched directly. Is there any way to save this current_user information on the localStorage?

I was trying to do this task using this code:

```
<script>
window.localStorage.setItem('cuser',current_user)
</script>
```

Comment: so what issue are you facing? please provide the error.

Comment: @PriyankMehta It says that current_user is not defined.

Comment: Can you post your complete code.. one issue can be in the script tag you need to use jinja variable and not current_user directly other can be you are not passing the current_user variable

Answer (score 0):

i would say jinja tags are needed:

```
<script>
    window.localStorage.setItem('cuser',{{ current_user }})
</script>
```

but like it was mentioned in the comments, this will only work if you pass current_user with the context for the response in the view